# I cant loop record from table which already use GROUP BY

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, loops

I want to loop record of field from a table. I use LEFT JOIN in my query and GROUP BY to prevent double loop in result. The query is successful but the result like this :

```
===========================================
|No|Nama Sekolah|Alamat|Telepon|Kompetensi|
===========================================
|1 |SMP 1       |JKT   |021231 | 1.TIK1   |
|2 |SMP 2       |BDG   |021232 | 1.RPL1   |
===========================================
```

If im not use GROUP BY the result will be like this :

```
===========================================
|No|Nama Sekolah|Alamat|Telepon|Kompetensi|
===========================================
|1 |SMP 1       |JKT   |021231 | 1.TIK1   |
|2 |SMP 1       |JKT   |021231 | 1.TIK2   |
|3 |SMP 2       |BDG   |021232 | 1.RPL1   |
|4 |SMP 2       |BDG   |021232 | 1.RPL2   |
===========================================
```

I want the result like this :

```
===========================================
|No|Nama Sekolah|Alamat|Telepon|Kompetensi|
===========================================
|1 |SMP 1       |JKT   |021231 | 1.TIK1   |
|  |            |      |       | 2.TIK2   |
|2 |SMP 2       |BDG   |021232 | 1.RPL1   |
|  |            |      |       | 2.RPL2   |
===========================================
```

Im using codeigniter framework.

Here is my view :

```
<table class='table table-bordered'>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <td>No</td>
            <td>Lokasi</td>
            <td>Alamat</td>
            <td>Telepon</td>
            <td>Kompetensi</td>
        </tr>
    </thead>
        <?php
        $i = 0;
        foreach ($row as $row) {
            $i++;
            echo"<tr>
                    <td>".$i."</td>
                    <td>".$row->nama_sekolah."</td>
                    <td>".$row->alamat."</td>
                    <td>".$row->no_telp."</td>
                    <td><ol>
                            <li>".$row->nama_jurusan."</li>
                        </ol>
                    </td>
                </tr>";
        }
        ?>
</table>
```

Here is model :

```
function getlokasi($jenjang){
    $sql = "SELECT s.nama_sekolah, s.alamat, s.no_telp, j.nama_jurusan FROM sekolah s LEFT JOIN jurusan j ON j.id_sekolah = s.id_sekolah WHERE s.id_jenjang = '".$jenjang."' GROUP BY s.id_sekolah";
    $q   = $this->db->query($sql);
    return $q->result();
}
```

Please help me. Thanks!

Comment: you can use group_concat function

Comment: @Chetan Ameta ok ill try it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So basically you want to show `ol` for TKL1,TKL2. If so
first use `group_concat` for `j.nama_jurusan` like

```
GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT j.nama_jurusan SEPARATOR ',')
```

in your query

and then in view explode the value from `,` and then use foreach loop to print it in `li`

just a guess, hope it will help.

Comment: I already try it but the error message show "Message: Undefined property: stdClass::$nama_jurusan"

Comment: Please tell me the line number and file name, shown with error

Comment: i change my query like this"SELECT s.nama_sekolah, s.alamat, s.no_telp, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT j.nama_jurusan SEPARATOR ',') FROM sekolah s LEFT JOIN jurusan j ON j.id_sekolah = s.id_sekolah WHERE s.id_jenjang = '".$jenjang."' GROUP BY s.id_sekolah" and the error"Message: Undefined property: stdClass::$nama_jurusan

Filename: ppdb/vlokasi.php

Line Number: 26"

Comment: please use print_r function on the object that is returned by the database. and see whats the output, if there is any property nama_jurusan, 
and please tell if
ppdb/vlokasi.php is your view file?

Comment: sorry i forgot give it name so the error message appear. i change it like this "GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT j.nama_jurusan SEPARATOR ',') AS nama_jurusan". thanks your answer is really work.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/97996/discussion-between-amit-sarwara-and-yoshioka).